# Can't get my keyless bulb socket working

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I have an old country home. I'm trying to get a porch lite to work.  The old porcelain fixture was cracked and had electrical tape holding it so I replaced with a porcelain keyless.

There are 2 sets of black and white wires in the box on the porch lid. Neither set is constant hot. When I switch on the switch inside the house,  one set in the box registers power.

I've wired it like it's supposed to be and several other configurations to try and get it to work but can't! I'm thinking the issue is they're isn't a constant hot at the box?

The switch is wired with one black and one white wire.  I only register power when I switch the switch in the on position.....

I need some help please?

Comment: Can you take some pictures of the ceiling and switch box?  Did the old fixture work?

Comment: It doesn't have a way for me to add pics....

Comment: But its a box with 2 sets of black and white wires and the switch has a white wire attached to the bottom and a black one attached to the top of the switch

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the light fixture box *and* all switch boxes involved please?  You should be able to [edit] your post (in "share edit"... under the left side of your post) and use the "mountain and sun" button in the toolbar to add pictures there

Comment: Why doesn't it work to use the pair that comes live when the switch is on? There's something you're not seeing or telling us.

Comment: Also, what are you using to test for power?

Comment: "*I've wired it like it's supposed to be and several other configurations to try and get it to work but can't! I'm thinking the issue is they're isn't a constant hot at the box?*"  There are two ways it could be set up.  A. light does not need a constant hot, it needs a switched hot. or B. one is constant and it sends power to the switch (*and then back*) which opens and closes the loop.  You need to explain what you **have** tried. **We need more info before we can try to help**.

Comment: So ... how was it wired *before* you removed the old one? Have you tried *that* configuration?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the light on 100% of the time, or when you flip the switch? Most people want it on only when they flip the switch. That's what you have. The hot wires go to one terminal, the neutral (white) wires go to the other on. The "extra" wires are feeding power to something else down stream, like maybe a post light in the yard or walkway lights? The intent would have been for that light to only come on when the switch was on as well, so it is attached to the same circuit.

You should be good to go, I just think you are over thinking this.

Comment: You're probably right, but that's taking a (not _too_ big) leap from the minimal info we've been given.